# Create SchemaCrawler diagram without descriptions

Tags: java, oracle, schemacrawler

I use *SchemaCrawler* to create database diagrams. The source is an Oracle database where the tables and columns do have a `COMMENT` set. Alas the text from the `COMMENT` does show up in the diagram which makes the diagram huge and barely unreadable. *SchemaCrawler* does have many options, but I could not figure out how to exclude table and column descriptions from the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrian,

Please use the `-noremarks` command-line switch, and table and column comments will not show up on the diagram. Please make sure you are using the latest version of SchemaCrawler for this switch to work, since it was added in a recent release.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)